# Some parts of Visual Studio 2015 are show in a different language

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I code with Visual Studio 2015 (Update 2) in English but some menus such as the Nuget Package Admin, the web Publish or the Code Lens labels change suddenly to Spanish.

I run Windows 10 in Spanish.

How can I fix them to stay in English?

Thank you very much!